# Normal subgroups of the Alternating group $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is $A_{n-1}$ a normal subgroup of $A_n$? If so, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n\geq 5$, $A_n$ is simple, meaning it has no nontrivial normal subgroups.

Comment: Should it not be 'no non-trivial _proper_ normal subgroups'?